# Pi4 Slow performance in local network over wi-fi

Tags: wifi, pi-4, samba

I'm running Pi4 4Gb as my Time Machine and Media Storage via smb server + PiHole. Speeds were always inferior, but I suspected problem was WD My Passport with HFS+ (for time machine) and exfat formatting (couldn't change it because occasionally I needed it to carry with me and stick in Windows PC's. So recently I reformatted it into ext4 and speeds for writing are about 5-10 MB/s from both laptop and smartphone.
Tests I've done:

- with connection to laptop type-c port with Ubuntu VM (for ext4) or MacOS speeds are 70-80 MB/s on writing
- HDD is connected to USB 3.0 port on PI
- Tested performance of HDD while connected to Pi `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/ext4/speedTestFile bs=20M count=5 oflag=direct` shown    99.6 MB/s
- iperf3 results are 63-89.7 Mbits/s over both 2.4 and Wifi 5 which represents my experience perfectly.Here's a small issue as in my current location both server (my laptop) and client(pi) for both wireless and  I can't connect any of them with cable. But still I believe speeds are crazy low and even thou my current router is from IP and pretty simple there is no load on it to have such speeds.
- Cloudflare speed test from laptop shows upload 560Mbps and download 273 Mbps with WIFI5, so I am kind of lost here.
- Performed Disk Speed test with black magic app from my laptop to network drive on Pi - read speed 5.6 MB/s, read is 4.4 MB/s, even slower then I thought.
  Any advice what can be done to increase speed of file transfer inlocal network? [write speed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eReAr.png)[image: iperf3 over WIFI5]

Comment: so, what speed do you want? The speed is limited to the slowest link in the "chain" ... and `WD My Passport` are notoriously slow as they use (in my experience of only 3 such devices) Shingled Magnetic Recording (SMR) - which is hot garbage

Comment: also, 80-90mbits/sec over wifi seems about standard for a raspberry pi - so, that'll be your limiting factor I guess

Comment: Well, you are not wrong I guess, but the fact it's same speed over 2.4GHz and 5GHz makes me think something is very wrong, also, as I added to post- actual write speed is about 45 Mbps. Regarding slowness of MyPasport- true, but then again, in direct connection to port speeds are closer to 90 MB/s

Comment: Sure, but the slowest link in the chain seems to be the wifi .. .so as you say `63-89.7 Mbits/s` - which is about 8 to 11 MBytes/s - so your `Disk Speed test with black magic app from my laptop to network drive on Pi` at most will be 11MBytes/s ... however, you say a `network drive on Pi` ... so, where is the actual drive connected, not to the pi, since you call it a `network drive` - so then you'll have wifi from laptop to pi, then wifi from pi to network drive ... wifi is garbage on the pi so you get what you get

Comment: I am sorry for confusion, English is not my native language so I can be unclear in explaining. Wifi can be bottleneck indeed, but I have doubts about it. Actual drive connected to Raspberry, disk speed test is running on laptop and measuring 4.6 MB/s (36.8 Mbps) write speed to it. This is way lower than iperf3 results of about 80 Mbps (which is also low for wifi5, in few meters from router, no other users of network, no background downloading and it is not even slightly higher then 2.4). Can samba settings be a bottleneck?

Comment: yes, samba can be a bottleneck, but you've shown that the disk speed is only 40mbit - so your iperf3 speed is irrelevant since it's twice the disk speed

Comment: @Jaromanda X 'wifi is garbage on the pi so you get what you get' that actually may be the answer :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151077/discussion-between-user11686813-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: Absolutely true. I guess I will have to accept that wifi on Raspberry or SMB over wifi is trash then )

Comment: What do you mean? Disk speed test performed on the same machine it is connected to is showing 90 MB/s. I pointed this in post and even attached picture of it. Once again, just to be clear: running speed test to locally connected drive gives write speeds of about 90MB/s. running speed test when its network attached, over smb, gives 4,6 MB/s.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, I misread the meaning of the comment where you said the disk write speed measured at *measuring 4.6 MB/s (36.8 Mbps)* - that's the throughput over wifi - soory for my misunderstanding - yeah, odd. disk speed and wifi speed both 80 to 90 - I guess it's samba over wifi that causes the horrendous slowdown

Comment: Yeah, guess that is the answer.